# Cannot ignore local changes with `git checkout` command

Tags: git, git-merge, git-checkout

I have this:

```
$ git checkout -- .
$ git pull
Updating 4411c31..db4498d
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        index.js
        utils.js
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

I keep trying `git checkout -- .` and it keeps giving me the same message. How do I obliterate the local changes here? I don't wish to keep my changes to index.js and utils.js.

Comment: You may need to do a `git reset` first, if the changes have already been staged.

Comment: If you wish to keep those changes, either `git stash` them or create a new branch `git checkout -b new-branch` and then commit changes. Change back to the original branch and then `git pull`

Answer (score 1):

My best guess would be that your files have been staged in git. That would mean that to get rid of the changes, you have to `git reset HEAD .` to unstage your changes, then `git checkout -- .` to actually get rid of them. If this is incorrect, could you please show the results of `git status`?